# How to get data from OO.ui.DropdownWidget?

Tags: javascript, oojs-ui, oojs

Given a ui with drowpdown menus built with OO.ui allowing to select human languages associated with their Wikidata value :

```js
  languagesA = new OO.ui.DropdownWidget({
    id: 'lqg-languagesA',
        label: 'Source language',
        menu: { items: [
      new OO.ui.MenuOptionWidget({ data: 'Q113', label: 'cmn - Mandarin Chinese' }),
      new OO.ui.MenuOptionWidget({ data: 'Q34',  label: 'mar - Marathi' }),
      new OO.ui.MenuOptionWidget({ data: 'Q209',  label: 'bre - Breton' })
    ]
 },
})
```

`languagesA.getData()` returns `undefined`.

`languagesA.getValue()` breaks.

**Q: Once a possibility is selected by the user, how to get the data value ?**

**Prototype:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/cqpr0zd3/1/ - contains A) `DropdownInputWidget` (fails to get value), B) `DropdownInputWidget` (works) and C) `ComboBoxInputWidget` (works).

**Official documentations :**

- DropdownWidget : https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/#!/api/OO.ui.DropdownWidget
- DropdownInputWidget :https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/#!/api/OO.ui.DropdownInputWidget
- ComboBoxInputWidget :https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/#!/api/OO.ui.ComboBoxInputWidget

Answer (score 0):

`DropdownWidget` is a broader shell for menus, which can contains various types of content and is therefor not gathering data, and has no `.getValue()` method. You have to dive in to reach the selected option using

```js
languagesA.getMenu().items.filter(item=> item.selected==true )[0].data)
```

**Alternative:** I eventually adopted the `ComboBoxInput()` with a better configured filtering.

```js
var baseLanguages = [
  { data: 'Q113', label: 'cmn - Mandarin Chinese' },
  { data: 'Q34',  label: 'mar - Marathi' },
  { data: 'Q209',  label: 'bre - Breton' }
];
var dropdown = new OO.ui.ComboBoxInputWidget({ // ComboBox
  id: 'lqg-languagesC',
  placeholder : 'Source language',
  options: baseLanguages,
  menu: {   filterFromInput: true, filterMode : 'substring' }
  // value: 'Q34',
});
```

Which add elegant features and has built-in `.getValue()`.